# pass variable from one page to another in angular 10

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to pass a variable from one component to another, I tried the following:

```
  @Output() public userFlow = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  this.userFlow.emit(this.userFlowThrough);
```

Now in my other page I want to receive it but just in the ts file and not the html as it will be used for internal logic.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
 @Input() userFlow: boolean;
```

Comment: you have to put the event emitter in a `service` file, import it in both components, then access this public variable `userFlow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following approach might be useful for you!

In the *receiver* component typescript, you have to create a method to receive the value of the userFlow variable like this:

```
export class ReceiverComponent {

constructor() { }

userFlow:boolean;

receiveBooleanValue($event) {
  this.userFlow= $event
 }
}
```

In *receiver* component html put the following:

```
<app-sender (booleanValueEvent)="receiveBooleanValue($event)"></app-sender>
<h1>{{userFlow}}<h1>
```

In the *sender* component typescript (*app-sender* selector), you should declare a booleanValueEvent variable with the @Output() decorator and set it equal to a new event emitter.

```
  export class SenderComponent {

  userFlow: boolean = true;

  @Output() booleanValueEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.booleanValueEvent.emit(this.userFlow)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In sender component .ts file you can add

```
sendData(){
    this.router.navigate(['receiverComponent'],{state:{data:this.userFlow}})
}
```

In receiver component .ts file add

```
userFlow = history.state.data;
```

Make sure to import router